# Unwanted blank page added to document when using tabularray and xcolor

Tags: color, tabularray

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-23>
```

TeX Live environment updated on 2022-08-25.  Using macOS BigSur 11.6.8

---

I have a (programmatically generated) table that (by design) takes up exactly one page using the tabularray package.  When I add the xcolor package, I get an error:
`Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1]` and a blank page prepended to my output.  If I remove a row from the table it works fine (unfortunately the table must be exactly 51 rows high on a single page).  Comment out the usepackage for xcolor and it works fine.  Any ideas what the problem is?  I'd really like to be able to use a little color in the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,oneside,letterpaper]{minimal}
\usepackage[verbose,nomarginpar,hmargin=.25in,vmargin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ l l },vlines,rowsep=1.125pt}
X99 & Xxxxx~9X~Xxxx  \\
X99 & Xxxxxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & Xxxxxxx~Xxxxx \\
X99 & Xxxxxx~xxx~Xxxxx \\
X99 & XxxXXxxxXxXxx \\
X99 & XxxxXxxxXxxxxxx \\
X99 & Xxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & XXXX \\
X99 & Xxxxx~Xx \\
X99 & Xxxxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & Xxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
X99 & Xxxx~Xxxxxxxx \\
X99 & XxxxXxxxxxxxXxxx \\
X99 & XxxXxxxXxxXxxxx \\
X99 & Xxxxx~Xxxxx \\
X99 & Xxxx~xx~xxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & XxxxXxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & XXXXX-XX-XXXXX \\
X99 & XXX~-~Xxxxx \\
X99 & XXXXX-XXX \\
X99 & XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX \\
X99 & XxxxXxxXxxxXxxxx \\
X99 & XX-Xxx \\
X99 & XxxxxXXX~Xxxxxxx \\
X99 & Xx-Xxxx \\
\\
X99 & XX~X9~Xxxx~Xxxxx \\
X99 & XX~X9~Xxxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & XX~X9~Xxxx~9 \\
X99 & XX~X9~Xxxx~9 \\
X99 & XX~X9~Xxxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & Xxxx~Xxxx~9 \\
X99 & Xxxxxxxx~Xxx~9 \\
X99 & X9~Xxxx~Xxxx \\
X99 & «« Empty »» \\
X99 & «« Empty »» \\
X99 & Xxxxx~Xxxxxx \\
X99 & «« Empty »» \\
X99 & «« Empty »» \\
X99 & «« Empty »» \\
X99 & «« Empty »» \\
X99 & X9~Xxxx~Xxxxx~XX \\
X99 & X9~Xxxxx~Xxxx~XX \\
X99 & X9~Xxxx~9~XX \\
X99 & X9~Xxxx~9~XX \\
X99 & X9~Xxxxx~Xxxx~XX \\
X99 & 9999~Xxxx~Xxx \\
X99 & Xxxxxxxxx \\
X99 & Xxxxxxxx~Xxx \\
X99 & Xxxxx~Xxxxxx~Xxx \\
X99 & Xxxx~X~Xxxxxxx \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

**tl;dr**
This is a minimum example that fails.  The real table is 16 columns wide.

This is a chart of the "slots" in a device and the "program" that is stored in the "slot".  The "slots" are in banks of 100, and there needs to be two banks per page.  There are multiple pages, but each is a separate table with explicit page breaks between them.

This is probably getting close to abusing TeX, but the prior version of this was a manual  LibreOffice spreadsheet and the TeX output is so much easier to read.

Comment: are you really using the minimal class? That is not a class meant for real documents.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting this behavior, but you should be able to avoid it by reducing the bottom margin or using even `\enlargethispage{1pt}`.

Comment: xcolor issues a \color command at the begin and that change spacing, but I don't know why it does it.

Comment: @frabjous That works around it for the test case I posted - let me go see if that will work in the real document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I am really using minimal.  This is a minimal document - two 1-page tables with simple headers and footers (think a draft print from a spreadsheet).  With the exception of this xcolor issue, I am getting exactly what I need from minimal.  If the doc needs to get bigger/more complex then I will switch to a more appropriate class.

Comment: @frabjous That has removed the extra blank page, but I'm still getting the Underfull \vbox message.  Please write that up as an answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well I'll be damned.  That's what I get for reading the documentation first.  It is the minimal class causing the problem.  If I switch it to article my extra blank page goes away (but a bunch more problems crop up - I can deal with those).  If you want to post that as an answer, go ahead.  If you don't I'll do it early next week.

Comment: The problem exists  with all classes, but the font size change if you switch the class and  so your concrete example change.

Comment: minimal ignores all the options like 12pt and letterpaper.